# Ruby test failure with exception

Tags: ruby

I have some tests in ruby which call some framework methods and classes. The problem I'm facing, is that some methods can throw exceptions, since they contact services not in my control. I want in the teardown method of the test to actually have the result of the test (success, failed with XXX), so I can do some stuff based on that. Is there a way I can do that (different from wrapping the whole test in a begin/rescue block) ?

Answer (score 0):

A code example of what you're trying to test might help. But depending on the framework API you're working with you can stub out the method that tries to contact the service, that would raise the exception. If you are calling one method that you are trying to test, and it also raises an exception (not very DRY/SRP code) then it makes it tricky. If that's the case, can either do a begin/rescue around that method call, or stub out the call to that larger method. The problem with doing the latter is it can obscure the value of your test more.

Comment: We're talking about integration tests. They can be quite long. To be more specific - selenium UI tests. The problem I'm facing is that when I call a method, that interacts with the UI, it might fail, in which case I want to take a screenshot. Stubbing would kill the reason of the test, wrapping separate methods i begin/rescue would require every call to be wrapped, which is also unpleasant. As I said, I can wrap the whole test method in begin/rescue, but that doesn't really look ok to me.

Comment: Stubbing external services with something like VCR or even just standard rspec mocks is not uncommon. Unit test or not. The idea is to test your code. The fact you're trying to capture an exception is raises has the same concern in terms of test validity